# Substandard TeXworks Preview Resolution

Tags: texworks

Note: I initially asked this question on TeX Stack Exchange (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701022/pdf-quality-issue-in-texworks-preview-especially-with-tikz-3dplot), but unfortunately, I did not receive an answer. I am reposting it here to get help from a broader community.

I've encountered an unusual problem in TeXworks that's been driving me up the wall. The issue revolves around the preview quality of my PDFs – it appears quite poor in the TeXworks preview, yet the actual PDF file is just fine.

This concern has become more pressing as I am using a Python script to execute LaTeX, and it seems to reflect the same subpar preview quality. Another user has indicated to me that they've faced the same problem without a clear solution; you can find a discussion about it in this post on the TeX Stack Exchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700093/bug-in-texworks-viewer. I've even tried a factory reset of my computer, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem.

This is what I'm getting in the preview:

[image]

This is what I'm getting in the PDF file:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
fill opacity=.5]
\tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
{1+(1/5)*sin(6*\tdplottheta)*sin(5*\tdplotphi)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```